# How point a directory in a Headless CentOS guest (on VirtualBox) to a directory on the host machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, shared-folders

I have the following setup:

HOST MACHINE: openSUSE LEAP (KDE) Linux
GUEST MACHINE: CentOS 7 (no GUI, command line only)
VM: VirtualBox 5.1.4

I have a directory on my host machine called `~/development/webfiles` and on my CentOS VirtualBox server, I have `/webapps/apps/webtest/public_html`.

I want the files for `/webapps/apps/webtest/public_html` to actually be from my host machine's `~/development/webfiles` directory.

How would I do this?

**EDIT: After [installing guest additions](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), I now have a folder:**

```
/media/sf_webfiles
```

How do I:

1. Point my public_html directory at that
2. Make it so it happens on startup

Answer (score 2):

I solved by doing the following:

1. [Install guest additions](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) in the CentOS server
2. Find the actual name of the shared folder: `ls -l /media`
3. Remove the existing "public_html" directory: `rm /webapps/apps/webtest/public_html` *(You may need to be root)*
4. Create a symlink to that directory: `ln -s /media/sf_webfiles /webapps/apps/webtest/public_html`

***EDIT:* This does *not* work for apache!**

A symlinked folder did not work - apache wouldn't read it no matter what permissions I gave the directory. Instead I had to mount it like this:

```
sharedfoldername /webapps/apps/destfolder    vboxsf  rw,uid=48,gid=48    0   0
```

I put that in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`